# HashMap: sorting key into alphabetical order with it's mapped values

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, hash

I asked a question here a while ago, fixed it, but now I have run into another problem.

```
This is jumblesOrdered ArrayList: [act, opst, dgo, art, aprt, fgor]
This is jumbles ArrayList: [atc, otsp, gdo, atr, arpt, grof]

This is dictionaryOrdered ArrayList: [act, act, act, dgo, dgo, opst, opst, opst, opst, opst, opst, art, art, art, aprt, aprt, aprt, fglo, fglo, fgor, gopr, glos]
This is dictionary ArrayList: [act, cat, tac, dog, god, post, pots, stop, spot, tops, opts, rat, tar, art, trap, tarp, part, flog, golf, frog, gorp, slog]

This is jumbleWordHM: {opst=otsp, art=atr, fgor=grof, aprt=arpt, dgo=gdo, act=atc}
This is dictWordHM: {opst=post pots stop spot tops opts, art=rat tar art, glos=slog, gopr=gorp, fgor=frog, aprt=trap tarp part, dgo=dog god, act=act cat tac, fglo=flog golf}Current Output:
```

---

Current Output:

```
atc act cat tac
otsp post pots stop spot tops opts
gdo dog god
atr rat tar art
arpt trap tarp part
grof frog
```

Desired Output:

```
arpt part tarp trap
atc act cat tac
atr art rat tar
gdo dog god
grof frog
otsp opts post pots spot stop tops
```

---

My code for printing out current output:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < jumblesOrdered.size(); i++) {
        String wordAnswer = jumblesOrdered.get(i);
        System.out.println(jumbles.get(i) + " " + dictWordHM.get(wordAnswer));

    }
```

The first word of each line is the scrambled word, and the subsequent words are the dictionary words that can be made from the scrambled letters.

My only problem is that I want to organize the scrambled words into alphabetical order like:

```
arpt - dictionary words
atc - dictionary words
atr - dictionary words
etc.....
```

Answer (score 2):

`HashMap` cannot be sorted, you should use some kind of a sorted map, like `TreeMap`, but maps can only sort by keys. (`TreeSet` could also be beneficial, it only takes a key and sorts them automatically.)

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) or [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html), which automatically use natural ordering on their elements.

Probably a `TreeMap` where the key is element 1, and the value is the `ArrayList` the element comes from. (A `TreeSet` is basically a `TreeMap` with only a key--no value.)